# Two tables with all rows including allocated based on id

Tags: mysql, join, union

Im trying to make this generic as it might help others in the future.

For an example i have two tables one with books and the other is the user with which book they have read, So ide like to display all the books and include a temporary column value as a (yes / no or 0/1), i have tried a join but the ( WHERE user_id = 3) clause only then return the one row and not all the other rows.

```
book.book_id     book.book_name
     10                 Book 1
     11                 Book 2
     12                 Book 3

-------------

user.user_id    user.book_id
      1                   10
      1                   12
      2                   11
      3                   12


Desired output:

user_id     book_id     temp_col_read
      3          10         0 // yes, on or null
      3          12         1 // or yes 
      3          13         0
```

Comment: You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for this case

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, sorry that my question dose't have any examples that i have tried. Left outer join did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple.  In the event that a user could read a book multiple times, I would go with `exists` in the `select`:

```
select b.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from reads r
                          where r.book_id = b.book_id and r.user_id = 3
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as user_read_book
from book b;
```

In MySQL, the `case` is not strictly necessary because a boolean expression is treated as 0/1 in many contexts:

```
select b.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from reads r
                where r.book_id = b.book_id and r.user_id = 3
       ) as user_read_book
from book b;
```

Comment: Yes a user could read a book multiple times using exists select worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join and where the join is unresolved  then is not read

```
  select 
        user.user_id
      , book.book_id
      , case  
            when book.book_id is null 
                then 'NO' else 'YES'  
        end as temp_col_read
  from book 
  left join user on user.book_id = book.book_id
```